Athens combined ticket and booking time slots
I want to buy a combined ticket for Athens main sightseeings. The ticket is valid for five days and includes access to 7 places including Acropolis, Roman Agora, etc. During the booking process, the page says:

Entrance exclusively at the time slot of your choice! We would like to inform you that from 01-04-2024, in all Archaeological sites and Museums where the e-ticket is applied, entrance is only possible during the time slot of your choice. Especially for the Acropolis, this is valid from 4/9/2023.

If I buy this combined ticket (it's a lot cheaper) how do I book time slots for these places?

This is what I ended up doing: Bought a 5-day ticket and went to Acropolis on the selected date/time. Went to other places on other days but no one asked about time slot at those places.
